# Problems with my Pieris shrub - has it been frostbitten?

Tags: damage, frost

have two pieris shrubs which were looking lovely. Suddenly noticed the new foliage is brown and shrivelled. Is this frost damage, and how should I treat them?

Comment: Possibly, but what part of the world are you in? Hard to make a judgement about frost if we don't know what's happened with your weather recently... and without a photo.

Comment: Pieris is pretty tough.  They are used to intermittent frosts.  Have you had an abnormal frost?  What zone do you live?  How old is this Pieris?  Is it a newbie from a nursery?  Where did you plant it, what have you added such as fertilizer?  Was this an indoor or greenhouse plant that was recently planted out of doors?  Could be sunburn. Could be over fertilization.  Send pictures and more information, please!